# PHP Include in lamp running in ubuntu server

Tags: php, include, apache2

I have installed LAMP in ubuntu server. and its working good.. i have a php application which has a folder structure the root folder has

- index.php
- {Database}

  - localhost.php
- {Modules}

  - module1.php
  - module2.php
  - module3.php
  - {MODULE3}

    - submod1.php
    - submod2.php

based on _GET the modules are included in index.php by

```
include('Modules/module2.php');
```

which works out perfectly well.. but in the **module1.php** when i try to include localhost.php  by

```
include('/Database/localhost.php');
```

it doesn't work out. why is that it's not working..

NOTE:the same code works perfectly in WAMP in my windows 7.

Comment: do you realize that include('/Database/localhost.php'); will try to include localhost.php that contains in /Database directory of server file system?

Comment: @heximal if that is because of alias i've checked the alias its been configred for /Icons /phpMyadmin alone..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a slash in front of "Database"

Comment: yes.. it works in windows 7.. i added a slash because that include is in a module file.

Comment: It will try to look for the file at the root of the file system.  Instead, you need to put the path to Database on the include path or use a relative path.

Comment: i removed the slash.. it works well now.. but why lamp and wamp are executing it in a different way.. even with the presence of slash it worked well in wamp.. why not the same for lamp..?

Comment: it has nothing to do with the wamp or lampp it depends on the configuration of php and include_path

Answer (score 2):

```
include('/Database/localhost.php');
```

the slash before /Database/ shouldn't be there because php tries to find the file from **/** (root folder).

Usually it's better to have a defined starting path point like:

```
define('DS', '/'); //Directory separator Unix
define('BASE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DS);
```

And then to use it as a base for all other included files.

Comment: i dont think so in module3.php i can include its sub modules easily by `include('MODULE3/submod2.php');` which works well..

Comment: ... just change this: include('/Database/localhost.php'); into this: include('../Database/localhost.php');